# Dealing with different response formats in Retrofit2 while using RxJava2CallAdapter

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm calling an endpoint that send responses in two different formats:

- `{ field1: VALUE, field2: VALUE }` if the response code is 2XX
- `{ message: ERROR_MESSAGE }` if the response code is 4XX

The POJO I'm using:

```
data class MyResponse(
    @SerializedName("field1") field1: String?,
    @SerializedName("field2") field2: String?,
    @SerializedName("message") message: String?
)
```

I'm using the `RxJava2CallAdapter` so, my Service interface looks like:

```
interface MyService {

    @POST(...)
    fun makeCall(@Body body: JsonObject): Single<MyResponse>
}
```

The issue is that if the response code is 4XX, if get an error instead of a `MyResponse` object with just the `message` field filled.

What I want is a way such that if the status code is:

- 2XX, I can access `field1` and `field2`
- 4XX, I can access `message`

when I subscribe to the return value of `makeCall()`

Answer (score 0):

Your response has an `errorBody` value included in it. So in your response you would need to do:

```
if(response.code() == 200) {
    //Success, continue as normal with your POJO
} else {
    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
}
```

`errorBody` can be converted to a JSON Object that would have your `{ message: ERROR_MESSAGE }` in it.

```
 try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(errorBody.string());
        errorMessage = object.getString("message");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'm calling `makeCall(body).subscribe()`. This gives me a RxJava2 `Single<MyResponse>`. From where will I get the response object used in your answer?

Comment: My bad @NightMare I was assuming you were using the .enqueue method from Retrofit